# how to launch lambda functions from AWS SAM and assign custom AWS IAM role to lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam, aws-lambda-layers

Right now in our CloudFormation templates we are creating few lambda functions, which then used multiple Cloudformation templates to do the automation task in order to have single click deployment of our product stack. Below is the sample CF template for CF lambda resources.

```yaml
HelmLambda:
  DependsOn: [ LambdaSGCleanup ]
  Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
  Properties:
    Handler: lambda_function.lambda_handler
    MemorySize: 512
    Role: !Ref EKSProvisionRoleArn
    Runtime: python3.7
    Timeout: 900
    Layers: [!Ref KubectlLayer, !Ref HelmLayer, !Ref CrhelperLayer]
    Code:
      S3Bucket: !Ref 'BucketName'
      S3Key: !Sub '${KeyPrefix}functions/packages/Helm/lambda.zip'
HelmLayer:
  Type: AWS::Lambda::LayerVersion
  Properties:
    Content:
      S3Bucket: !Ref 'BucketName'
      S3Key: !Sub '${KeyPrefix}functions/packages/helmLayer/lambda.zip'
```

In above lambda function we have two dependencies. One is IAM role and Layer ARN. IAM role and Layer ARN this create on run time.

Now we want to put our product on AWS-Marketplace and we came to know that creating lambda function as above is not supported by AWS-Marketplace guidelines.

We are thinking of converting our lambda functions to AWS SAM. but we are not able to figure out how to use IAM role and Layer Arn which are created at run time during the CF  stack deployment with AWS SAM and create lambda functions.

Any help or guidance on this will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

So if you want to reference the role and layer created by SAM as per the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-function.html#sam-function-role) you need to define them in the template, below is a working template  :

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  sam-with-layers

  Sample SAM Template for sam-with-layers

Resources:
  LambdaRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-lambda-role
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action: 'sts:AssumeRole'
            Principal:
              Service: lambda.amazonaws.com
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: WriteCloudWatchLogs
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: 2012-10-17
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - 'logs:CreateLogGroup'
                  - 'logs:CreateLogStream'
                  - 'logs:PutLogEvents'
                Resource: 'arn:aws:logs:*:*:*'
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Functionn
    Properties:
      CodeUri: hello_world/
      Handler: app.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.8
      Role: !GetAtt LambdaRole.Arn
      Layers:
        - !Ref MyLambdaLayer

  MyLambdaLayer:
        Type: AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion
        Properties:
            LayerName: MyLambdaLayer
            ContentUri: lambda-layer/
            CompatibleRuntimes:
              - python3.8
            RetentionPolicy: Retain
```

and below is my dir structure:

```
.
├── README.md
├── hello_world
│   ├── app.py
│   └── requirements.txt
├── lambda-layer
│   └── python
│       └── lib
│           └── python3.8
│               └── site-packages
│                   └── hello.py
├── samconfig.toml
└── template.yaml
```

Comment: in our case we want to keep SAM on AWS repository and then deploy lambda through Cloudformation templates at the time of deployment.
and we create IAM role at the time of CF stack deployment and these IAM roles we want to use with Lambda which are being deployed by using SAM which are in AWS sam repository.

Comment: yes, you can provide static IAM Role ARN while deploying the function. I am assuming we are not talking about cross-referencing the role arn between stacks.

Comment: by referring to the AWS docs was able to figure out how to use IAM role with AWS SAM to assign IAM roles to AWS lambda functions.

Comment: yes, the CF and SAM snippet which i posted earlier same we are using in our CF templates.

Answer (score 0):

So if you look at the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-function.html), you can see that you just use Role and Layer as properties. There isn't much of a refactoring to do for you.

Answer (score 0):

below is the sample snippet which we are using in order to make AWS LAMBDA functions which are created through AWS SAM templates to use custom IAM role which get created at the time of CF stack deployment.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  sam-with-layers

  Sample SAM Template for sam-with-layers

Parameters:
  EKSProvisionRoleArn:
    Type: String
Resources:
  HelmLambda:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: 's3://BUCKET/functions/packages/Helm/lambda.zip'
      Handler: lambda_function.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.7
      MemorySize: 512
      Timeout: 900
      Role: !Ref EKSProvisionRoleArn
      Layers:
        - !Ref HelmLambdaLayer
        - !Ref KubectlLambdaLayer
        - !Ref CrHelperLambdaLayer

  HelmLambdaLayer:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion
    Properties:
      LayerName: HelmLambdaLayer
      ContentUri: 's3://BUCKET/functions/packages/helmLayer/lambda.zip'
      CompatibleRuntimes:
        - python3.7
        - python3.6
      RetentionPolicy: Retain
  KubectlLambdaLayer:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion
    Properties:
      LayerName: KubectlLambdaLayer
      ContentUri: 's3://BUCKET/functions/packages/kubectlLayer/lambda.zip'
      CompatibleRuntimes:
        - python3.7
        - python3.6
      RetentionPolicy: Retain
  CrHelperLambdaLayer:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion
    Properties:
      LayerName: CrHelperLambdaLayer
      ContentUri: 's3://BUCKET/functions/packages/crhelperLayer/lambda.zip'
      CompatibleRuntimes:
        - python3.7
        - python3.6
      RetentionPolicy: Retain
Outputs:
  HelmLambdaArn:
    Description: Helm Lambda Function ARN
    Value: !GetAtt HelmLambda.Arn
```

below is snippet which we are using in CF templates to call above AWS SAM template to deploy lambda functions:

```
  HelmLambda:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Application
    Properties:
      Location:
        ApplicationId: 'ARN_TO_SAM'
        SemanticVersion: 0.0.5
      Parameters:
        EKSProvisionRoleArn: !Ref EKSProvisionRoleArn
```